# which is the best approach in designing my asp.net application architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, architecture

I'm just asking for a general advice. I have a web app consisting of

- ASP.NET webforms project (which also has jQuery dialogs)
- Domain Layer / Business Logic
- DataAccessLayer
- WebService class

Now the way i have designed this project is that when a read routine is called from the client (jQuery ajax), the client calls a webservice method, which then calls my data access layer methods, the DAL returns a datatable to my web service method, the web service method then creates the relevant Business Logic class from the returned DAL object which is then returned to the jQuery ajax method as a response.

Is this the right routine or should it be this way, the client calls a web service method, the web service method creates a business logic class, the Business Logic class calls the DAL which returns a DAL object to the Business Logic Class, which then returns an updated Business Logic class to the web service and finally returning it to the client as jQuery ajax response

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the way you mentioned later, but you should have a model class that you will pass back and forth between BLL and DAL. so for example:

Your web service has a method called GetCarById(int carId)

your web service should create an object of CarBll e.g. carBll, and pass the request to this bll e.g: carBll.GetCarById(carId)

then your CarBll should call CarDll for the actuall database call, this will look something like this: carDll.SelectCarById(carId)

carDll returns you CarModel (which is a class with just properties in it, filled with data)

CarModel is then passed back to service by CarBLL ... and so on